# Finding the frequency per second from an audio file

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, fft, frequency

I am currently making a game, similar to Audiosurf. I am trying to find the frequency of an audio file(like .mpg3 or .wav) at every second. Based on the value I will build the level. I have been doing a lot of research on this topic. I have a way to get the samples within the audio file, i am using the unity engine to make this game. I am thinking about breaking the samples into samples per second(using the transfer rate), then do an FFT on each of those and then find the highest frequency within each. Am I on the right path? Can anyone ofter any suggestions or if I am not on the right path, can anyone one correct me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "The frequency of an audio file" doesn't make sense, really.  Does your file only contain a single sine wave?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right path with the FFT part and splitting your samples into bins. Here is a library for that: http://www.fftw.org/

Where it gets hairy is with picking your frequency, let me tell you off the bat just throw away the highest frequency in the spectrum, it's part of the static. *Maybe* you could use the lowest frequency to catch the bassline, but likely the bass drums and even atmospheric sound effects will interfere there.

Now provided you do find some heuristic that allows you to pick the "frequency" at a given moment in the song, this most likely doesn't have correlation to the music itself. You are really better off re-working your idea to use frequency *spectrum* at each moment, not just a single frequency.

EDIT: The fourier transform will provide you with an array of complex numbers, each represents the amplitude as the real component and phase as the imaginary component for its bin.

Comment: "Part of the static" - in general there will be cross-spectrum noise, and spectral leakage.  No bin will be zero-valued...

Comment: I meant it from a musical perspective, I've found in the studio that usually the highest frequency harmonic with non-trivial amplitude is still not actually music but instead just background noise from the recording situation.

Comment: Thank you both for your replies. I've been doing some more research and I found bins and real and imaginary results from the fft. Can someone explain these? Also I found that to get a frequency its the sqrt(real*real + imaginary*imaginary), what does this mean?